# Django-admin-tools and missing list of actions

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I installed in my django project django-admin-tools, quick instalation, without custom dashboard. After this every 'lists of custom actions' ([django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)) of my models disappeared. Anyone know how to turn on this lists with django-admin-tools?